# How can I calculate the time until collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

I'm programming a 1 dimensional physics simulator in python. How do I calculate the amount of time until two particle points that are traveling towards eachother collide? I am using the equation:

```
time = (m2.pos - m1.pos) / (m1.velocity - m2.velocity).
```

You can assume m1 is always on the left, and m2 is always on the right. This equation works fine in my program if both points are traveling in the same direction at slightly different speeds, but when m1 has a positive velocity and m2 has a negative velocity, that gives the denominator of my equation a negative number which produces a negative amount of time until the next collision.

Comment: If v1>0 and v2<0, then v1-v2=v1+v2>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If m1 has a positive velocity and m2 has a negative velocity, you get `(m1.velocity - m2.velocity) = (positive - negative) = positive`. On the other hand if the signs are switched, you'll get a negative result because the particles are moving away from each other.

Comment: I realize now that this equation was fine. My program doesn't work properly once m1 of positive velocity and m2 of negative velocity collide, and now I'm starting to think that the problem could be related to the fact that at that instant, they share the same position.